# Google Cloud Container Build trigger crashes during gradle build

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was trying to setup a build trigger for an kotlin app that is build using gradle. For that I put together the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:jdk8 as builder

WORKDIR /home/gradle/project

COPY . .

WORKDIR ./Kuroji-Eventrouter-Server

RUN gradle shadowJar

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /home/gradle/project/Kuroji-Eventrouter-Server/build/libs/kuroji-eventrouter-server-*-all.jar kuroji-eventrouter-server.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "kuroji-eventrouter-server.jar"]
```

And that file works on my machine with docker build and it starts normally on google container registry however during the `RUN gradle shadowJar` task it crashes with some gradle error:

```
Step 5/9 : RUN gradle shadowJar
 ---> Running in ddd190fc2323
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
[91m
[0m[91mFAILURE: [0m[91mBuild failed with an exception.[0m[91m
[0m[91m
[0m[91m* What went wrong:
[0m[91mCould not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
[0m[91m> [0m[91mCould not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().
[0m[91m
[0m[91m* Try:
[0m[91mRun with [0m[91m--stacktrace[0m[91m option to get the stack trace. Run with --info[0m[91m or --debug[0m[91m option to get more log output. Run with [0m[91m--scan[0m[91m to get full insights.[0m[91m
[0m[91m
[0m[91m* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[0m[91m
[0m[91mBUILD FAILED in 3s
The command '/bin/sh -c gradle shadowJar' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: exit status 1
[0m
```

I tried building the Image on docker HUB and the same thing happend: https://hub.docker.com/r/usbpc/kuroji-eventrouter-server/builds/bnknnpqowwabdy82ydxiypc/

This is very confusing to me as I thought containers should be able to run anywhere and not depend on the enviroment. What can I do to make google build my container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a file permission problem. Using the --stacktrace option I found that the gradle process didn't have permissions to create a folder inside the sources.

The solution I would like to do is use the `--chown=gradle:gradle` option on the COPY instruction, unfortunatly this it not supported in the google cloud yet.

So the solution is to add `USER root` before executing the gradle build.